# Return data from axios.all in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to implement a function that gets the data from two endpoints using axios.all.
The function is the following:

```
    const items = async () => {
let promisesTest = []
let one = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/health?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
let two = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/vue?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"

let miArray = []

promisesTest.push(axios.get(one));
promisesTest.push(axios.get(two));

let apiResponse = []

miArray = await axios.all(promisesTest).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        apiResponse.push(responses[i].data)
    }
    return apiResponse
}))
console.log('mi array', miArray)
return miArray
    }
```

I can correctly see the data in the variable "myArray" but when I invoke the function I cannot visualize said data and what I see when doing console.log (items) is Promise {}

Could you guide me to correctly obtain the data returned by the items function? From already thank you very much

Comment: `return await Promise.all(promisesTest)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const axios = require('axios')
const items = async () => {
    let promisesTest = []
    let one = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/health?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
    let two = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/vue?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
    
    let miArray = []
    
    promisesTest.push(axios.get(one));
    promisesTest.push(axios.get(two));
    
    let apiResponse = []
    
    miArray = await axios.all(promisesTest).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            apiResponse.push(responses[i].data)
        }
        return apiResponse
    }))
    return miArray;
    }
```

call function like this

```
items().then(res => {
    console.log('response', res);
});
```